# Openlayers 5 scaleline has gives wrong results

Tags: openlayers

I am using Openlayers 5 (modules from NPM) and I am having a problem with a scaleline in my map.

```
// from https://epsg.io/2264.js
proj4.defs('EPSG:2264', '+proj=lcc +lat_1=36.16666666666666 +lat_2=34.33333333333334 +lat_0=33.75 +lon_0=-79 +x_0=609601.2192024384 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=us-ft +no_defs');

register(proj4)

opts = {
  extent: extent,
  center: [
    (extent[0] + extent[2]) / 2,
    (extent[1] + extent[3]) / 2
  ],
  maxResolution: 1777.77777777778,
  minZoom: 2,
  maxZoom: 22,
  zoomFactor: 2,
  zoom: 2.5
}

// ---------------
// I get different results in scaleline depending
// upon which of these projection lines is used

opts.projection = 'EPSG:2264';
//opts.projection = new Projection({code: 'EPSG:2264'});

// -------------

let view = new View(opts);
let map = new Map({
  view: view,
  layers: []
});
map.addControl(new ScaleLine({
    units: 'us'
}));
```

I get different scaleline results depending upon which projection line above that I comment out.

When the map first appears, using the first projection line above gives a 2 mile scaleline. Using the second one gives a 5 mile scaleline. This is the same length scaleline and map extent but a different distance label on the scaleline.  The second seems to be the correct one.

Shouldn't these give the same results?

Am I doing something wrong or should I be filing an issue?

Comment: The first is correct.  If you set an OSM layer in the map it reprojects correctly.  `new Projection()` is used to set up custom projections and requires other options such as a point resolution function.

Comment: But the first gives me an incorrect scalebar distance label. I guess this is a bug?

Answer (score 1):

It may be a bug, if you check this OpenLayers example https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/scaleline-indiana-east.html which opens at 20 miles it's a very long 20 miles on the ground.  There seems to be a problem when projection units are in feet, I've checked meter projections and there was no problem.

I've found two solutions

1. Use your first method, but add a getPointResolution function to the projection returned by proj4 and assume (unlike web mercator) that resolution doesn't vary across the projection:

`import {get as getProjection} from 'ol/proj.js';`

`getProjection('EPSG:2264').setGetPointResolution(function(r) { return r; });`

2. Use your second method, but for it to work in all cases (e.g. reprojection) it needs more options:

`opts.projection = new Projection({
    code: 'EPSG:2264',
    units: 'us-ft',
    getPointResolution: function(r) { return r; }
});`

Comment: In the same example for OpenLayers 3 https://openlayers.org/en/v3.20.1/examples/scaleline-indiana-east.html the scale line opens at a realistic looking 50 miles, so presumably a bug has been introduced since version 4.

Comment: Your two examples seem to show the same results I'm getting. (only 2 miles and 5 miles)  I'll submit an issue on github.

Comment: issue submitted https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/9193

Comment: Thanks for the bug report. The issue has already been fixed in master.